# use data-attr to dynamically pick css custom property

Tags: html, css, css-variables

Given the following snippet:

```css
:root{
  --warning: rgb(230, 126, 34);
  --warning-bg: rgba(230, 126, 34, 0.1);

  --important: rgb(52, 152, 219);
  --important-bg: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.1);

  --caution: rgb(231, 76, 60);
  --caution-bg: rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.1);
}

[data-type]{
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 12px;
}

[data-type="warning"]{
  background-color: var(--warning-bg);
  border: 1px solid var(--warning);
}

[data-type="important"]{
  background-color: var(--important-bg);
  border: 1px solid var(--important);
}

[data-type="caution"]{
  background-color: var(--caution-bg);
  border: 1px solid var(--caution);
}
```

```html
<div class='block' data-type='warning'>
  <span>Block: Warning</span>
</div>

<div class='block' data-type='important'>
  <span>Block: Important</span>
</div>

<div class='block' data-type='caution'>
  <span>Block: Caution</span>
</div>
```

Can I use the `data-type` attribute to pick a custom property (var) from CSS, so that I don't have to repeatedly add the styles for each `data-type`?

> The `data-type` property comes from an external source and the colors are always in sync with all the `data-type`(s)

Something along the lines of:

```css
[data-type]{
  background-color: var(--#{attr(data-type)}-bg);
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid var(--#{attr(data-type)});
  margin: 12px;
}
```

> NOTE: Using SASS/LESS is a no-go due to factors beyond my control.

Comment: no this is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not averse to using a small piece of Javascript to perform the necessary assignments then perhaps this might be of interest.

This uses `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue` to retrieve the variables and `setProperty` to assign the dynamically created style to the elements.

```js
let root=document.documentElement;
let col=document.querySelectorAll('div[data-type]');
    col.forEach( n=>{
      n.style.setProperty('background-color',getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--'+n.dataset.type+'-bg') );
      n.style.setProperty('border',['1px solid',getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--'+n.dataset.type)].join(' '));
    });
```

```css
:root{
  --warning: rgb(230, 126, 34);
  --warning-bg: rgba(230, 126, 34, 0.1);

  --important: rgb(52, 152, 219);
  --important-bg: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.1);

  --caution: rgb(231, 76, 60);
  --caution-bg: rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.1);
}

[data-type]{
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block' data-type='warning'>
  <span>Block: Warning</span>
</div>

<div class='block' data-type='important'>
  <span>Block: Important</span>
</div>

<div class='block' data-type='caution'>
  <span>Block: Caution</span>
</div>
```